# Why are the tags on my page arranged reverse alphabetically?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed. They are opposite of what I though they would be!!

Have a look:
https://superuser.com/users/8829/eskay

Comment: Oh, god! That's the first time I've ever really looked at SuperUser. The colors! It burns us, precious!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's just a sort ordered by (number of posts, name) that's descending, instead of ordering by number of posts descending and name ascending.

Given that this goes against the expected ordering, I think I'd call this a very minor bug. Mind you, the tags page itself doesn't seem to have any (obvious) secondary ordering...

Comment: Its ordered by ordering by "number of posts descending and name descending" See the tags with number of posts = 1

Comment: @eSKay: Yes, that's what I mean. I suspect that it's *meant* to be ascending in name.